# How to set user picture on GDM?

Tags: ubuntu, gdm

I installed fluxbox on top of Ubuntu server, to get a minimal desktop installation. On the gdm login screen, I see a X instead of the user picture. How do I set this picture? What is the minimal software I need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.

The icon at the top of the login screen is called the greeter icon. It is located in /usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/64/computer.svg. It can be installed with `ubuntu-mono` package.

User icon can be set by copying an image into `~/.face` file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about newer GDM versions (user's profile picture in Gnome Shell alias Gnome 3), you could use the following:

Pictures are stored in the folder `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/[user name]`

The [user name] is of type *image/png* format with a size of 96x96 pixels

Under the folder `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` you have a similar file [user name] that is a *.desktop* format - for example

```
[User]
Language=en_GB
XSession=ubuntu
Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/dad
```

The `Icon=` is not created unless you assign a picture in *Users and Accounts*

If you assign one of the stock pictures the file will contain - for example

```
[User]
Language=en_GB
XSession=ubuntu
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/soccerball.png
```

Thus –as you can see– just create an `Icon=` entry in `/var/lib/AccountsService/user/[user name]` to point to your PNG file or overwrite the icon in the similarly named `/var/lib/AccountsService/icons` folder.

Last tested on Fedora 33 in April 2021.

**[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/64308/135671)**